# What does it mean for a method to be asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

What is an asynchronous method.  I think I know, but I keep confusing it with parallelism.  I'm not sure what the difference between an asynchronous method is and what parallelism is.

Also what is difference between using threading classes and asynchronous classes?

**EDIT**

Some code demonstrating the difference between async, threading and parallelism would be useful.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between doing I/O in a separate thread vs the asynchronous patterns that use [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Have a look at here- For Async: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164036.aspx. For MultiThreading: http://arstechnica.com/features/2002/10/hyperthreading/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### What are asynchronous methods?

Asynchronous methods come into the discussion when we are talking about potentially lengthy operations. Typically we need such an operation to complete in order to meaningfully continue program execution, but we don't want to "pause" until the operation completes (because pausing might mean e.g. that the UI stops responding, which is clearly undesirable).

An asynchronous method is one that we call to *start* the lengthy operation. The method should do what it needs to start the operation and return "very quickly" so that there are no processing delays.

Async methods typically return a token that the caller can use to query if the operation has completed yet and what its result was. In some cases they take a callback (delegate) as an argument; when the operation is complete the callback is invoked to signal the caller that their results are ready and pass them back. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback.aspx) is a commonly used callback signature, although of course in general the callback can look like anything.

#### So who does actually run the lengthy operation?

I said above that an async method starts a length operation, but what does "start" mean in this context? Since the method returns immediately, where is the actual work being done?

In the general case an execution thread needs to keep watch over the process. Since it's not the thread that called the async method that pauses, who does? The answer is, a thread picked for this purpose from the [managed thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx).

#### What's the connection with threading?

In this context my interpretation of "threading" is simply that you explicitly spin up a thread of your own and delegate it to execute the task in question *synchronously*. This thread will block for a time and presumably will signal your "main" thread (which is free to continue executing) when the operation is complete.

This designated worker thread might be [pulled out of the thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) (beware: doing very lengthy processing in a thread pool thread is not recommended!) or it might be one that [you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkb1k2x8.aspx) just for this purpose.

Comment: Except that a big advantage of asynchronous processing is that it actually does not block any threads.

Comment: @svick: That would ultimately depend on the operation and the relevant facilities provided by the OS. However, the blocking part was not really germane to the discussion so I edited it out among a couple of other things. Thanks for weighing in.

Answer (score 21):

First off, what is a method and what is a thread? A method is a *unit of work* that either (1) performs a useful side effect, like writing to a file, or (2) computes a result, like making a bitmap of a fractal.  A thread is a *worker* that performs that work.

A method is *synchronous* if in order to use the method -- to get the side effect or the result -- your thread must do *nothing else* from the point where you request the work to be done until the point where it is finished.

A method is *asynchronous* if your thread tells the method that it needs the work to be done, and the method says "OK, I'll do that and I'll call you when it is finished".

Usually the way an asynchronous method does that is it *makes another worker* -- it grabs a thread from the pool. This is particularly true if the method needs to make heavy use of a CPU. But not always; there is no *requirement* that an asynchronous method spins up another thread.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So one thread tells the method "do this" and then waits for a response, and antoher thread actually executes this response; and the first thread can do some useful work while it waits for the response, correct?

Comment: @CrazyMan: That's one way it can work, yes, but asynchrony does not *require* two workers. Consider a workflow where you put some bread in the toaster and then cook some eggs while you're waiting for the toast to pop. There's only one "thread" -- one cook -- in the kitchen but you manage to get work done on the eggs while you're waiting for the toast.

Answer (score 10):

Say you need to clean the house, cook the dinner and put the children to bed.

Synchronous:

You clean the house, then cook dinner, then put the children to bed.

Parallel:

You hire 3 people to clean the house, cook dinner and put the children to bed. But you don't trust them so keep a supervisory role, looking over them and waiting for them to finish. Only when they've all finished do they get paid.

Asynchronous:

You one child to clean the house and another to cook dinner. When each have finished their chores they put themselves to bed, while you put your feet up with a glass of wine in front of the tv.

Comment: The last paragraph is funny but could be more accurate. I'd say that "asynchronous" would be "you put the water on to boil and *while it is coming to boil* you have some time to pick up the coats that are on the floor. Then put the noodles in the water, and then you have some time to start a load of laundry. Then while the laundry is running you can eat dinner. Then you can put the kids to bed, and then finish cleaning the house. The point of asynchrony is that you *split up the work into small parts* such that you can do something else while waiting for a high-latency operation.

Comment: Yeah but the main point is, parallel, main thread waits for child threads to complete before continuing. Asynchrous, child threads work away while main thread does it's own thing. (In the simplest possible terms!) :)

Comment: @anothershrubery No, that's not true.  First off, you can have the main thread doing work in a parallel environment.  You could even have the main thread not observing the other threads in a parallel environment.  Parallelization means that there is more than one thing doing work, no more, no less.  Asynchrony means starting work, doing something else, and then potentially doing something based on the results of the work that was started earlier.  This *might* involve parallelization, but it also may not, as Eric's example described.  You can do housework asynchronously but not in parallel.

Comment: @Servy: Or, another classic example: You can still work while you're pregnant, but nine women can't get together and make a baby in a month. The operation is asynchronous -- you can do something else while you're waiting for the result -- but it is not *parallelizable* -- portions of the task cannot easily be farmed out to independent workers.

Answer (score 1):

First you got to understand that if you want parallelism all the structure need to be parallel, I mean that if you have an asynchronous method you need a asynchronous call.
In webservices or web stuff, asynchronous methods can be (just one of the many ways) called with AJAX which is asynchronous. In one method you can have multiple threads, this is the key difference between async methods and multiplie threads.
And the main: the difference between a standard method and a async method is that if you make 2 calls to a standard method at the same time to the same controller with a asynchronous caller (like AJAX) the second call will just begin when the first call has already completed, if the methods that you called were asynchronous both the calls will begin at the same time, with multiple-cores servers it can achiev twice (2 calls) the standard speed.
The speed of the parallelism is measured by this [law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law).